# Port old X10 Example to version 2.5

Tags: parallel-processing, x10-language

I have an old X10 example in class which I'm trying to compile.

```
import x10.array.Array;
import x10.io.Console;
...
public static def main(args: Array[String](1)) {
    val regionTest = 1..12;
    val testArray = new Array[Int](1..12, (Point)=>0);
    for ([i] in testArray) {
        testArray(i) = i;   
        Console.OUT.println("testArray("+i+") = " + testArray(i));
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it seems to be outdated. I could figure out by myself that you have to write `public static def main(args:Rail[String])` now. The definition of `val regionTest = 1..12` seems to be ok. The syntax for the array must be wrong, all following lines maybe too. I tried to fix this with [this guide](http://x10.sourceforge.net/documentation/guide/2.1.0/pguide.pdf), but did not succeed.

My setup is working, the initial class in a new X10 Eclipse IDE project runs.

Could somebody help me port this to version 2.5.x?

Answer (score 1):

There were a number of non-backward-compatible changes in X10 version 2.4, which require code changes - see the guide to ["porting to X10 2.4"](http://x10-lang.org/documentation/practical-x10-programming/porting-to-x10-2-4.html).

Your example would be updated as follows:

```
import x10.regionarray.Array;
import x10.regionarray.Region;
import x10.io.Console;
....
public static def main(args:Rail[String]) {
    val regionTest = Region.makeRectangular(1..12);
    val testArray = new Array[Int](regionTest, (Point)=>0n);
    for ([i] in testArray) {
        testArray(i) = i as Int;
        Console.OUT.println("testArray("+i+") = " + testArray(i));
    }
}
```

This demonstrates a number of important changes:

- (Lines 1--2) The general-purpose array classes have moved from the `x10.array` package to `x10.regionarray`.  These classes are no longer imported by default.
- (Lines 6--7) There is no implicit type conversion from `LongRange` (`1..12`) to `Region`.  A `Region` object must be explicitly constructed and passed to the `x10.regionarray.Array` constructor.
- (Line 7) The default integral type is now `Long` instead of `Int`.  An `Int` literal must be suffixed with the character '`n`' as in '`(Point)=>0n`'.
- (Lines 8--9) The index type for array classes has changed from `Int` to `Long` (to support very large data structures).  Therefore the exploded `Point` iterator `for ([i] in testArray)` now yields `i:Long` instead of `i:Int` - which means the cast `i as Int` is now required when assigning to an `Int` array element on line 9.